# Join two different databases on the same server, different usernames and passwords

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a join between two different databases. Each has separate usernames and passwords (no it is not possible to grant privileges). How can I connect to the second from the mysql terminal so that I can execute something similar to the following:

```
select * from db1.table1 a left join db2.table2 b on a.joincolname=b.joincolname;
```

I connected to the first database using the following from the command line:

```
mysql -u db1user -pdb1pass
```

and then connected to db1 using

```
use db1;
```

Let's assume that the usernames and passwords for db1 and db2 are db1user, db1pass, db2user and db2pass respectively. Thanks.

Comment: Replication might be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple credentials applied to a SINGLE mysql connection. Whatever user you're connecting as will need the rights to access both databases.

The only way around this is to use a client-side script, with two separate connections, using the separate credentials, and then doing the joining in the client - which is highly inefficient.